# Realtime image-stitching using a CMOS camera array

Tags: image-processing, dsp-core

I am very new to DSP so please excuse any brevity...

I have to design a 4x4 CMOS camera array and stitch the images together for further processing... I have tried doing that with opencv but the frame rate count drops drastically... So i want to do the Stitching part using some Image Processor Kit which can take multiple CMOS camera input and stitch them and give me a single image as output and the fps should be 60fps ideally atleast 48 fps...

The problem is that I have a very basic level knowledge of DSP so I would need some suggetions regarding which Image Processor or Kit I should use to make a quick prototype... Also what kind of input does the Processor need from the camera(ttl, usb, etc)...

Thanks in advance